# Azure B2C linking federated login to a locally created user account

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've been trying to follow this: [link-local-account-with-federated-account](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/link-local-account-with-federated-account)

Basically all I'm looking to do is create (invite) a user from an external tenant as a federated user, and be able to assign custom attributes to that user upon creation.

However there are a few things I just can't figure out from the readme. Would really appreciate if someone could shed some light on these:

1. When creating the user object (the local one), a issuerAssignedId is assigned, which is apparently the oid of the federated user. How do you get that before the user has performed a login?
2. In the created user object, there is SignInType.oidToLink, yet in the instructions directly below it talks about signInNames.oidToLink. Is there a typo somewhere, or have I missed something here?
3. in the readme it talks about oidToLink, but in the TrustFrameworkExtensions xml file, it has objectIdToLink. Is this just a typo or have I missed something?

The application base is DotNet + Angular using Microsoft Authentication Library for Angular.

I've done a lot of reading and just can't figure this out, and can't find any articles which describe the process clearly. Thanks in advance :)

I did the following steps:

1. Ran the setup tool as per the instructions
2. Created the custom attribute extension_requiresMigrationBool
3. Uploaded the custom policies in the repo linked above (edited any keys etc. in the files)
4. Created a user via graph in DotNet using the following code (can confirm this user is successfully created with all custom attributes):

```
            var userRequest = new User
            {
                AccountEnabled = true,
                UserPrincipalName = "<some_email_com>#EXT#@<domain>.onmicrosoft.com",
                UserType = "Member",
                DisplayName = user.Email,
                MailNickname = "NewUser",
                PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                {
                    ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
                    Password = "Test1234"
                },
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { ExtensionAttribute("custom0"), false },
                    { ExtensionAttribute("custom1"), someValue },
                    { ExtensionAttribute("custom2"), someValue },
                    { ExtensionAttribute("custom3"), someValue },
                    { ExtensionAttribute("requiresMigrationBool"), true }
                },
                Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity> {
                    new ObjectIdentity()
                    {
                        SignInType = "oidToLink",
                        Issuer = "<domain>.onmicrosoft.com",
                        IssuerAssignedId = "<WHERE DO I GET THIS OID?>"
                    }
                }
            };
```

5. I run the above SignUpOrSignIn policy, and attempt to login using the same email address used in the newly created user - <some_email_com>
6. I get the following message:

```
Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' and cannot access the application 'app_id' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account.
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this up in some detail [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/linking-a-federated-login-against-an-existing-azure-ad-b2c-local-account-ea2db2fc2252).

1. That's the objectID ("issuerAssignedId") of the user in the "issuer", which is contoso.com i.e. the writer has pre-defined an Identity array. This would normally be added during federation.
2. Refer to [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/searching-for-user-attributes-using-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies-bb0175b37853).

SignInType.oidToLink is an attribute in the identity array.

signInNames.oidToLink is how you search for this identity.

3. See 1. objectIdToLink maps to "issuerAssignedId".

Other posts that may help are [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-identities-and-linking-them-in-azure-ad-b2c-33b72fcbfd25) and [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/another-look-at-account-linking-in-azure-ad-b2c-ea6462e5736e).

To answer the second part of your question, they are mappings in the federation technical profile, e.g.

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
```

In the sample, you have to get oidToLink outside of the PowerShell e.g. by looking at the Entra ID user attributes (assuming you are federating with Entra ID).

Example of Identity [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes#identities-attribute).